# wrap dollar amount between $ and . in a price (ex:$666.99)

Tags: jquery, regex

I have a page with a lot of prices listed in this standard US format: $4.99, $600.00, etc.

Since they all have a '$' and a '.', I'm trying to grab the dollar numbers from between those 2 characters and wrap just the dollar amount in a span.

example: **$4.99** becomes **`$<span>4</span>.99`**

thanks!!!

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**REGEXP:**

```
(\b\d+)(?=\.)
```

**ORIGINAL TEXT:**

```
$4444.99
```

**RESULT:**

```js
const regex = /(\b\d+)(?=\.)/gm;
const str = `\$4444.99`;
const subst = `<span>\$1</span>`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

**See:** https://regex101.com/r/pA0XdW/1

Comment: this is awesome! just what i was looking for. Thanks!!!

Comment: you are welcome. *Remember to mark me as the answer to your question. if I help you.*

Answer (score 0):

You could use a span with a class to wrap the dollar amount, but not the whole price.

`$<span class="dollar-value">4</span>.99`

Then you can use jquery to get the dollar value using the dollar-value class (.dollar-value)

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for anyone interested.

```
$('.price').html(function(i, html) {
    html = $.trim(html);
    return html.slice(0, 1) + "<span>" + html.slice(1,-3) + "</span>" + html.slice(-3);
});
```

It's not exactly what I was asking for, but does the trick. It simply trims the first ($) and last 3 (.00) characters, and wraps the text in between them in a span.